# Распространение vcruntime140.dll в дистрибутиве своего приложения

Tags: библиотеки, распространение

Есть у меня приложение, использующее Qt (сборка в Qt Creator с помощью cmake).
Создан дистрибутив с помощью Inno Setup, все необходимые библиотеки включены в него, кроме одной - vcruntime140.dll (ставится отдельно с помощью пакета Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2015). Т.е., по факту, из этого пакета нужна только одна библиотека - vcruntime140.dll.
Возможно ли ее включить в свой инсталлятор, или это нарушит лицензионные требования Microsoft?
Либо делать статическое использование библиотеки при сборке проекта?
Как правильно?

P.S. Вариант установки пакета vc_redist.exe не подходит для обычных пользователей - он требует прав администратора.

Comment: Установка приложений в любом случае требует прав администратора.

Comment: Не в любом. В данном случае приложение устанавливается в AppData\Local и AppData\Roaming.

Comment: Сваливать исполняемые файлы в AppData - это не установка. Если система нормально настроена, то их оттуда даже запустить не удастся.

Comment: Ну почему же сваливать? Обычная установка инсталлятором. Посмотрите, к примеру, Telegram Desktop.

Comment: Спасибо. Более-менее понятно. А какой метод стали бы использовать вы, к примеру (исходя из контекста вопроса топика)?